# Insert values in junction table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, junction-table

I have three tables in database:

```
 trips(trip_id(pk), trip_name(unique), user_id(fk))

 places(place_id(pk), place_name(unique))

 trips_places_asc(trip_id(fk), place_id(fk))
```

Since, many trips can have many places, I have one junction table as above.

Now, if user insert places to the trip, the places will be added to `places` table and the trip will be associated with the places in `trips_places_asc` table.

So, if i write query like:

```
INSERT INTO places (place_name)
VALUES ('XYZ')

INSERT INTO trips (trip_name)
VALUES ('MyTrip')
```

Then, How to store `trip_id` and `place_id` in Junction or Association table `trips_places_asc`?
will I have to fire two queries? plz help.

**Note:** There are many questions on SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888234/data-insertion-with-junction-tables) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892784/update-a-junction-table-with-new-values). but, none of them have accepted answer or not even an answer. so, plz do not mark as duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have `place_name` and `trip_name` as unique just do as:

```
insert into  trips_places_asc ( trip_id, place_id )
    values (  (select trip_id from trips where trip_name = 'MyTrip'),
              (select place_id from places where place_name = 'XYZ') );
```

Or depending what comand you are using to insert (php command I mean) you can return the ids after the inserts and use it to run an insert command with it.

It will be like: (using mysqli* functions )

```
$query = "INSERT INTO trips (trip_name) values ('MyTrip')";
$mysqli->query($query);
$trip_id = $mysqli->insert_id;

$query2 = "INSERT INTO places (place_name) values ('XYZ')";
$mysqli->query($query2);
$place_id = $mysqli->insert_id;

$query3 =  "insert into trips_places_asc ( trip_id, place_id ) "; 
$query3 .= " values ($trip_id, $place_id)";
```

Note, I'm doing this directly from my mind, so maybe you have to adjust some syntax error or be concerned about prepared statements.

**EDIT** 
Though I should add the proper documentation link about this command: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: thanks..But what if I remove unique key from trip_name?

Comment: Then you will have to use the second option. I will edit the answer with a little example using php commands. wait a bit.

Comment: Are you there sir? I'm waiting for your answer.

Comment: Hello sir, both cases run successfully. But, I have one problem : let suppose, If I run query in your first case twice, then I will have multiple records of same foriegn keys in the association table. what to do in such kind of situation?

Comment: Then, create an array and store the ids of each entity you will run your query multiple times. Make sure to add it in order, because the command `$mysqli->insert_id` will return just the last id inserted. So, the logical way in your model would be insert a trip and lots of places (in my point of view), so you store the tripid and create an array to places and each place id you put on this array then iterate it inserting the trip with each id.

Comment: what i want to do is to avoid this: http://oi60.tinypic.com/soo1n9.jpg - multiple records of pairs

Comment: You have to change that table to make both columns as PK, it would be like: `alter table trips_places_asc add constraint _pk_somename primary key (trip_id, place_id)` that way the database will make sure that duplicate values can't happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64053/discussion-between-xyz-and-jorge-campos).